# Check if any entries in a list ends with a specified string

Tags: python, list

So, lets say I want to find the entries that end in `foo`.

You'd think you do something like:

`results = list.endswith("foo")`

And then print out the entries that end in the string `foo`

How would I do this?

Comment: I for one wouldn't think that. Do you want to check if `any` (hint!) have that ending, or get those that do? Have you tried making a list of those that do? Testing the length of it?

Comment: Check if ANY entries in a list ends with `foo` and then print out the results

Comment: The result of checking if any have would either be true or false. Seriously, what *have* you tried?

Answer (score 5):

The following works, but let's call the list myList:

```
result = [x for x in myList if x.endswith('foo')]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for entry in list:
    if entry.endswith("foo"):
        print(entry)
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
for entry in [entry for entry in list if entry.endswith("foo")]:
    print(entry)
```

[Examples at regtester.com](http://rextester.com/OLGYN8569)

Answer (score 2):

[`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.endswith) is a method for string objects. You cannot apply to a list of strings and expect it to magically be applied to every element. You could use a list comprehension, though :

```
results = [string for string in list if string.endswith("foo")]
```

This will return a list of strings ending with "foo". You can then check if it contains any element.